# Can I use Dropzone.js to send files directly to Facebook instead of first uploading them to my sever?

Tags: facebook, dropzone.js

I can post images to a user's event stream using [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) using HTML, Javascript and PHP:

HTML

```
<form action="PHP/uploads.php" class='dropzone' id='fbDropZone'></form>
```

Javascript

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = true;
Dropzone.options.fbDropZone = {
    init: function () {
        fbDropZone = this;
        $("#removeAllImages").click(function () {
            fbDropZone.removeAllFiles();
        });
    },
    previewTemplate: '<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview"><div class="dz-details"><div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div><div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div><img data-dz-thumbnail /></div><div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div><div class="dz-success-mark"><span>✔</span></div><div class="dz-error-mark"><span>✘</span></div><div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div></div>',
    paramName: "file",
    maxFilesize: 5,
    maxFiles: 1,
    autoProcessQueue: false
};
```

And then this PHP is called when a `<DIV>` is clicked on:

```
$config = array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'scope' => $required_permissions,
'fileUpload' => true,
'allowSignedRequest' => false,
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$facebook->setAccessToken($_COOKIE['fbAccessToken']);
$eid = $_COOKIE['eid'];

$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$storeFolder = 'uploads';

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];       

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds;

    $targetFile = $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

    $photo_return = $facebook->api($eid.'/photos', 'POST', array('source' => '@'.$_FILES['file']['name'], 'message' => 'This post from a DropZone'));
}
```

Thing is I'd like to pass the image directly from the user's drive to FB without going via my server. Can anyone point me towards some code to do this? Or is it just not possible as security issues prevent me from knowing exactly where the file is on a user's device/computer?

Answer (score 0):

When a user posts a file, you receive the file stream. You may know the user's file path, but it's irrelevant if you're not in the same computer.

As far as I know, you should be able to send the file stream from your server to Facebook directly with no security issues, but sending just a file path would be of no help.

If you really want to send a file without receiving it in your server, then you should program a Javascript-only solution, but that would require a Facebook JS API with file upload support. I'm not aware if such a thing exists.

Comment: You can certainly program a Javascript-only solution that POSTs a file directly to facebook from your custom JS client. See here: https://gist.github.com/nseo/2910244 -- This only uses plain form file input, not Dropzone, but I'm sure you can make it work with some data-massaging, since Dropzone doesn't do the POST work and just prepares the files for you.